# How to ignore the 60fps limit in javafx?

Tags: javafx-8

I need to create a 100fps animation that display 3d data from a file that contains 100 frames per second. But the AnimationTimer in javaFx allows me to get 60fps only. How to get over it?

Answer (score 9):

**Removing the JavaFX Frame Rate Cap**

You can remove the 60fps JavaFX frame rate cap by setting a system property, e.g.,

```
java -Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true MyApp
```

Which is an [undocumented and unsupported setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439861/where-can-i-find-java-prism-render-possible-options-and-documentation).

Removing the JavaFX frame rate cap may make your application considerably less efficient in terms of resource usage (e.g. a JavaFX application without a frame rate cap will consume more CPU than an application with the frame rate cap in place).

**Configuring the JavaFX Frame Rate Cap**

Additionally, there is another undocumented system property you could try:

```
javafx.animation.framerate
```

I have not tried it.

**Debugging JavaFX Frames (Pulses)**

There are [other settings like `-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true`](http://JavaFX%208%20has%20a%20Pulse%20Logger%20(-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true%20system%20property)%20that%20%22prints%20out%20a%20lot%20of%20crap%22%20(in%20a%20good%20way)%20about%20the%20JavaFX%20engine's%20execution.%20There%20is%20a%20lot%20of%20provided%20information%20on%20a%20per-pulse%20basis%20including%20pulse%20number%20(auto-incremented%20integer),%20pulse%20duration,%20and%20time%20since%20last%20pulse.%20The%20information%20also%20includes%20thread%20details%20and%20events%20details.%20This%20data%20allows%20a%20developer%20to%20see%20what%20it%20taking%20most%20of%20the%20time.) which you could enable to help you debug the JavaFX architecture and validate that your application is actually running at the framerate you expect.

> JavaFX 8 has a Pulse Logger (`-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true` system property) that "prints out a lot of crap" (in a good way) about the JavaFX engine's execution. There is a lot of provided information on a per-pulse basis including pulse number (auto-incremented integer), pulse duration, and time since last pulse. The information also includes thread details and events details. This data allows a developer to see what is taking most of the time.

**Warning**

Normal warnings for using undocumented features apply, as [Richard Bair from the JavaFX team](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2390862) notes:

> Just a word of caution, if we haven't documented the command line switches, they're fair game for removal / modification in subsequent releases :-)

Comment: I can confirm that the java -Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true MyApp works  perfectly when added as a VM arg.

Comment: Tested using Oracle 1.8.121 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit, the `-Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true` works. The `-Djavafx.animation.framerate` does not work, either on its own or with the fullspeed property.

Comment: Alternate link: [_JavaOne 2012: JavaFX Graphics Tips and Tricks_](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2074652/javaone-2012-javafx-graphics-tips-and-tricks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Fullspeed=true will give you a high framerate without control (and thereby decrease performance of your app as it renders too much), framerate doesn't work indeed.
Use:

```
-Djavafx.animation.pulse=value
```

You can check your framerate with the following code. I checked if it actually works too by setting the pulserate to 2, 60 and 120 (I have a 240Hz monitor) and you see a difference in how fast the random number changes.

```
 private final long[] frameTimes = new long[100];
    private int frameTimeIndex = 0 ;
    private boolean arrayFilled = false ;
    Label label = new Label();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        AnimationTimer frameRateMeter = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long oldFrameTime = frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] ;
                frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] = now ;
                frameTimeIndex = (frameTimeIndex + 1) % frameTimes.length ;
                if (frameTimeIndex == 0) {
                    arrayFilled = true ;
                }
                if (arrayFilled) {
                    long elapsedNanos = now - oldFrameTime ;
                    long elapsedNanosPerFrame = elapsedNanos / frameTimes.length ;
                    double frameRate = 1_000_000_000.0 / elapsedNanosPerFrame ;
                    label.setText(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f" +", Random number:" + Math.random(), frameRate));
                }
            }
        };

        frameRateMeter.start();
```